# Does div html tag is supported in android or not?

Tags: android, html, textview

I want to parse the string response which is coming in html div tag.
I am using `Html.fromHtml()` and displaying the text into android textview.
But the expected output is not achieved...

I have read on certain websites that div tag is supported. please clarify

Comment: Please add code and the output you are expecting.

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html

Comment: @FrankN.Stein already visited your given link..

Comment: Let me suggest you using a `WebView` instead of a TextView, then.

Comment: What about jsoup library....?

Comment: @Rohit5k2 <div class="description" style="margin-top: 5px; clear: both; float: left; text-align: justify; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: normal; orphans: auto; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 1; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px;"><br><\/div>
Cream and orange net lehenga saree is beautified with embroidered, resham, zari, hemline and all over with patch border adds grandeur.

Comment: I want to extract "Cream and orange net lehenga saree is beautified with embroidered, resham, zari, hemline and all over with patch border adds grandeur. " this text

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) to display html in your app. 
Its more elegant than parsing your content, and you dont have much to worry about.